# the compactness of a disc under product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathcal{O}_1$ and $\mathcal{O}_2$ be an open subset family of $\mathbb{R}$ as
$$\mathcal{O}_1 = \{~(a, \infty)~ | a \in \mathbb{R}\} \cup \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset\},\\\mathcal{O}_2 ~ \text{is the Euclidean topology.}$$
Moreover, let $\mathcal{O}$ be the product topology of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{O}_1)$ and $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{O}_2)$. In this case, is a unit disc $D =\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}~|~ x^2 + y^2 \leq 1\}$ a compact subset of $(\mathbb{R}^2, \mathcal{O})$ ?

As a simpler case, I understand that a closed interval $[-1,1]$ is a compact subset of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{O}_1)$. However, I do not know what to do in the case above.

Sorry if my English is clumsy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is compact.

More generally:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{T}'\subseteq \mathcal{T}$ be another topology. If $X$ is compact in $\mathcal{T}$ then it is compact in $\mathcal{T}'$.

and it follows from a simple observation that a cover in $\mathcal{T}'$ is also a cover in $\mathcal{T}$.

So, all you need to know is that the disc is compact in the Euclidean topology. Since the Euclidean topology contains your $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Thank you for your great help! Now I know what I should focus on.